# Using independent Vue project within another as node package

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, node-modules, vuex

I am stuck in some architectural changes in my projects and needs some guidance to get going. Following is my problem.

**Context**
I started with a single Vue application which included a number of components like querying, visualizations, CRUD, etc. Querying itself is a combination of several independent components (mainly forms). 
Later on, I started another application with a completely different use-case but it also needs the querying functionality. So, I simply included querying components within that too.

**Scenario**
Everything is working fine now, but it's quite a mess to manage updates/changes to Querying components in both of these separate projects. Now I am thinking of making the querying component as a separate independent tool/package and include it in both the projects. Doing that will ease up the code managing of  Querying components for me as then I 'll only have to make changes to a single code base.

**Problem Statement**
The main Problem is the querying component, which I am looking to separate, relies heavily on centralized state management by Vuex using its mutations, actions, and getters.
I have seen a number of tutorials and blogs on how to make a single Vue component as an npm packge. But my use case is a bit different, In my case, as I have stated earlier, I have a number of components (depending on Vuex mutations and actions) within Querying.
I am now confused on how to make Querying separate with its own Vuex store and then include it within an application with that application's respective Vuex Store.

I have never made a node package before, maybe it's something trivial and basic which I am not getting, so please pardon my less knowledge in the domain.

Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to give you a proper answer.
Imagine you have a npm package with the *querying component* and the *store*.
Then, your npm package should export something like (check below) to be able to build a new Vue instance with the store and the component:

```
import Querying from '[path]/components/Querying'
import store from '[path]/store';

export default {
    QueryingComponent: Querying, store: store
}
```

The code above should be in the entry point of your *webpack.conf*. If the entry point is a file named index.js then it should be inside this file.

```
module.exports = {
entry: resolve('/src/index.js'),
...
```

In the other side, after you have installed the package, you will have the component and the store available. So that you can instance Vue and render that in another part of the page by just creating a new div with another id in the *index.html* page.

```
import components from '[your package]';
const yourStore = components.store;
const yourQueryingComponent = components.QueryingComponent;

new Vue({
  yourStore,
  render: (h) => h(yourQueryingComponent),
}).$mount('#another-app');
```

Hope that helps!